# Ajax Live Streaming Responses "What is being searched live"

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, jquery, xml-rpc

I do have a CakePHP based application., And I dugg through xml-rpc & inbuilt ajax. The only thing I am missing is.. How to do this.

Users will come and type something in a search form...

Results will be generated using /sites/searchresult action.

I will be having a separate url /sites/live

This should display currently being searched keyword using some scriptaculous or jquery.

I need to know.. How to actively keep sending keywords & its result array to some other cakephp action or a plain php page.

As far as I researched all xml-rpc or ajax things are.. One request and One response kind of approaches.

I need the client or receiver page should wait.. And server or sender have to actively send results.

How?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is accomplished through long-polling, typically to a "comet" server.  CakePHP, as generally run through Apache, is not capable of this.

You should just use a [jquery timer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) to continually query the backend for changes, and update the results as appropriate.